# How to exclude specific fields from the query condition?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am creating a webapp for users to query data from mongodb. I have front end using react and backend with nodejs hooking up mongodb.

I have included all relevant matching conditions under aggregate function. However I would like to have the effect of commenting out certain key-value pair, (by this I mean nullifying the effect of the query field condition). For example,

```
router.get('/getmongo', function(req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONN, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;    
    db.aggregate([
      {
        $match:{
          'employmentStatus':/employed|unemployed/i,
          'gender':{$in:["male","female"]},
          'age':{$gte:20, $lte:30}
      }
    },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$employmentStatus",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }}
    ]).limit(4).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify(docs))
    db.close();
  })
})
```

Let say on front end, the user does not select the option of age, which means there is no specification from the user's end on the age criteria. Usually for this case, users would comment out or remove the whole line of age query on MongoDB GUI, leaving only employmentStatus and gender as the only two criteria to query. I was looking into mongoAPI but can't find any useful tool to replicate that effect. Any idea or suggestion?
(I am using Mongo v2.3.3 by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding conditions in the Query at MongoDB side, you should build your query conditionally based on user input.

Whenever user selects the columns, build the `$match` clause using those columns and values. In that way, it will be quite dynamic.

**Example PseudoCode:**

```
var queryObject = {};

if(age.selected)
          queryObject.add(ageCondition)
if(employmentStatus.selected)
          queryObject.add(employmentStatusCondition)
if(gender.selected)
          queryObject.add(genderCondition)

.....
......
```

You can build some logic like this in Node.js.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!